# How to add an add-on to change your name in the comments and become all by the first name only in wordpress What is the fincation used

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add an add-on to change your name in the comments and become all by the first name only in wordpress What is the fincation used

An example of this first picture is as usual and the second as I want to implement it to show only the first name of all commentators

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress themes usually use the nickname of a user in this comment template. You can change that in the theme itself of with a child theme.

[comment author](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_author)

You just have to modify the according function to what you want it to display:

[this answer might help you with that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/248591)

Comment: Some themes are not available in this so I want to make them a constant addition